# Regular expression doesn't match if a character participated in a previous match

Tags: regex

I have this regex:

```
(?:\S)\++(?:\S)
```

Which is supposed to catch all the pluses in a query string like this:

```
?busca=tenis+nike+categoria:"Tenis+e+Squash"&pagina=4&operador=or
```

It should have been 4 matches, but there are only 3:
s+n
e+c
s+e

It is missing the last one:
e+S

And it seems to happen because the "e" character has participated in a previous match (s+e), because the "e" character is right in the middle of two pluses (Teni **s+e+S** quash).

If you test the regex with the following input, it matches the last "+":

```
?busca=tenis+nike+categoria:"Tenis_e+Squash"&pagina=4&operador=or
```

(changed "s+e" for "s_e" in order not to cause the "e" character to participate in the match).

Would someone please shed a light on that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct: The fourth match doesn't happen because the surrounding character has already participated in the previous match. The solution is to use lookaround (if your regex implementation supports it - JavaScript doesn't support lookbehind, for example).

Try

```
(?<!\s)\++(?!\s)
```

This matches one or more `+` unless they are surrounded by whitespace. This also works if the plus is at the start or the end of the string.

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!\s)  # assert that there is no space before the current position
         # (but don't make that character a part of the match itself)
\++      # match one or more pluses
(?!\s)   # assert that there is no space after the current position
```

If your regex implementation doesn't support lookbehind, you could also use

```
\S\++(?!\s)
```

That way, your match would contain the character before the plus, but not after it, and therefore there will be no overlapping matches (Thanks Gumbo!). This will fail to match a plus at the start of the string, though (because the `\S` does need to match a character). But this is probably not a problem.

Comment: Since not all regex implementations support look-behind assertions, you should only use the look-ahead assertion.

Comment: Thanks, that is just what I needed! But in the case I would have to also implement this in JavaScript, what solution would you suggest?

Comment: I have just edited my answer with a slightly less elegant solution that will also work in JavaScript.

Comment: @Tim: I believe there is a pretty standard technique for reformulating regexes with lookbehinds into ones with lookaheads. I don’t use it myself because I never use a language without them (Perl, Java, Python), so it doesn’t spring quickly to mind. It might be good to look up though because now I’m wondering whether it’s also a work-around for the restriction against variable-width lookbehind, since lookaheads never suffer from that.

Comment: @tchrist: This should be possible since you could translate a lookbehind into a lookahead that starts at an earlier position in the string; however, it will become difficult not to "overrun" the current position in the string, especially with variable-length lookbehind. If you can find a link to a generic technique, that would be most interesting.

Comment: @Tim: the not-overruning part would *seem* to be to use the standard anything-but this-formulation: `(?:((?!unwanted)(?s).)*)`, somehow or other, but if I find the link to the technique, I’ll post it.

Answer (score 2):

In a consecutive match the search for the next match starts at the position of the end of the previous match. And since the the non-whitespace character after the `+` is matched too, the search for the next match will start after that non-whitespace character. So a sequence like `s+e+S` you will only find one match:

```
s+e+S
\_/
```

You can fix that by using look-around assertions that don’t match the characters of the assumption like:

```
\S\++(?=\S)
```

This will match any non-whitespace character followed by one or more `+` only if it is followed by another non-whitespace character.

But tince whitespace is not allowed in a URI query, you don’t need the surrounding `\S` at all as every character is non-whitespace. So the following will already match every sequence of one or more `+` characters:

```
\++
```

Comment: I'd prefer `(?!\s)` to `(?=\S)` because the latter will fail if there is a plus at the end of the string. But the best idea is of course to drop the lookaround entirely if it's not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex:

```
(?<=\S)\++(?=\S)
```

To match only the `+`'s that are surrounded by non-whitespace.